# Calculating the probability that any given entity will be chosen

Tags: matlab, probability, combinatorics

I have a set of balls in a bag (`A/B/C/D`) each with an assigned weight `([0.1 0.3 0.1 0.2])` that describes the relative probability that each ball will be chosen over another. I then wish to choose `n` number of balls per round **sequentially**, record the balls chosen and put them back into the bag, resetting the system for the next iteration.

I'm interested in calculating the overall probability of obtaining any given ball.

As a simplistic example, if n = 1

Ball B - `0.3/(0.1+0.3+0.1+0.2)` = `0.4286` = Ball B would be chosen in 42.86% of the rounds.

The complication arises when n = >1.

For example, if n = 2 - what is the probability that Ball B will be one of the balls chosen in any given round?

Is there a way MATLAB can calculate such information?

Comment: Are balls chosen with or without replacement? Can `n` exceed the number of balls?

Comment: No n cannot exceed the total number of balls.

Comment: And they are sampled without replacement, right? Once you take a ball, you only have three balls to sample from

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: If all balls had the same probability that would be a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), for which there's the Matlab [hygepdf](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/hygepdf.html) function. But in your case the probabilities are different, so I think you need to do the computations manually.

Comment: With Matalb it would be very easy to _simulate_ instead of compute the value you want. In other words, use a Monte Carlo approach. Is that acceptable for you? That would not give the exact value, but a random approximation to it

Comment: Do you want to calculate the probability a priori analytically, or does a good approximation with samples suffice?

Comment: A random approximation would likely suffice. Do you have an example of such a simulation? I have done some simulation before on MATLAB but not a great deal.

Comment: Will your weights always be rational?

Comment: @BillBokeey No, they will not always be rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of random approximation :

1/ Normalize your weights vector so that it contains probabilities as stated by Marcus Müller in his answer

```
probabilities=weights/sum(weights);
```

2/ Now let's suppose that we have `P` balls indexes with integers `{1,2,...,P}` and we want to draw `n` of them per experiment. What we need to do is to get *random samples without replacement* from the set `{1,2,...,P}`, with respect to the probability vector `probabilities`.

```
s1=datasample(1:P,n,'replace',false,'weights',probabilities)
```

This should give you a sample following your probabilities. What you still have to do, though, is to repeat the process a big enough amount of times and count how many times each ball is in your sample in order to calculate your probabilities. (i.e

```
P(ballA)=Number of times ballA was in sample/Total Number of samples
```

Something along the lines of :

```
TotalSamples=1000;
Res=zeros(TotalSamples,n);

for ii=1:TotalSamples

   Res(ii,:)=datasample(1:P,n,'replace',false,'weights',probabilities);


end

%% Prob ball A :

PA=sum(sum(Res==1))/TotalSamples;

%% Vector containing all probs :

FinalProbs=zeros(P,1);

for jj=1:P

FinalProbs(jj)=sum(sum(Res==jj))/TotalSamples;

end
```

Running this on you example, i get final probabilities of :

```
%% TotalSamples=1000
FinalProbs =

0.3180
0.7310
0.3250
0.6260

%% TotalSamples=100000

FinalProbs =

0.3303
0.7440
0.3294
0.5964
```

Note that it's totally normal that your probabilities sum up to more than 1, because the events are not disjoint (You can draw different balls per sample if n>1..)

Comment: I did originally try this method however `datasample` simply returns the input weights - I was under the impression that when n > 1, this should not be the case.

Comment: Did you run `datasample` with all the arguments i gave you?

Comment: This would have been my approach too. You can equally use `randsample` instrad of `datasample`

Comment: I believe `randsample` doesn't allow using weights without replacement - http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html

Comment: Just ran with your updated answer - seems fine now! It's quite interesting to see that (when scaling FinalProbs such that sum(FinalProbs) = 1), some values have increased relative to the original probabilities whilst others have decreased - something I did not expect!

Comment: Don't scale FinalProbs such that sum(FinalProbs)=1, your events are not disjoints when n>1! (for example with n=2, the events "A has been drawn" and "B has been drawn" have a non empty intersection consisting of all the time you have drawn A and B in the same sample)

Comment: I wouldn't ordinarily - I was just interested in comparing them to the input values (unless there is a better way to do this?)

Comment: Well as they are not disjoint, what you compute will not really have any sense. Only things you can say with this are things like "i have 74% chance of drawing ball A if i draw 2 balls without replacement from this set with these weights". If you want disjoint events, you'll have to consider every possible draws (e.g for n=2 with 4 balls A/B/C/D you'll have disjoint events with AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD)

Comment: @BillBokeey You are right. `datasample` is necessary

Comment: Given your astounding reputation on SO and the awesomeness of all your answers @LuisMendo, i must warn you that your last comment will be printed 10 times and displayed in my office :D

Comment: @BillBokeey Hahaha. Your answer was very nice indeed!

Answer (score 0):

That information doesn't need to be calculated, it's already there in the form of the weights. These weights are simply proportional to the probabilities, and you'd actually have the probabilities if you just made it so that `sum(weights)==1`; hence,

```
probabilities = weights ./ sum(weights);
```

is your solution.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question